# Memory for array property not allocated before Constructor?

Tags: c++, memory-management, constructor, struct

When I run the program and new a NetworkEditor, it will corrupt at the constructor because of it reads out of the array's memory.
When I debug it one loop by one loop, it will be ok!?
*Why? Didn't it allocate enough memory for the array before it entered the constructor?*

In my class, I have two properties:

```
/*NetworkEditor.h*/

    class CNetworkEditor : public CDiagramEditor
    {...
        VLLink* VL_list[10];
        VLLink* temp_VL_list[10];
    }
```

and in the constructor, I initialize the arraies:

```
/*NetworkEditor.cpp*/
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        VLLink* vl_link = NULL;
        while(vl_link == NULL)
        {
            vl_link = new VLLink;
        }
        vl_link->preLink = NULL;
        vl_link->nextLink = NULL;
        vl_link->link = NULL;

        VLLink* vl_link2 = NULL;
        while (vl_link2 == NULL)
        {
            vl_link2 = new VLLink;
        }
        vl_link2->preLink = NULL;
        vl_link2->nextLink = NULL;
        vl_link2->link = NULL;

        VL_list[i] = vl_link;
        temp_VL_list[i] = vl_link2;
    }
```

and VLLink is defined as:

```
typedef struct struct_VLLink
{
    CPhysicalLink* link;
    struct_VLLink* preLink;
    struct_VLLink* nextLink;
}VLLink;
```

If I change it to:

```
    VLLink* VL_list2[10];
    VLLink* temp_VL_list2[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VL_NUM; i++)
    {
        VLLink* vl_link = NULL;
        while(vl_link == NULL)
        {
            vl_link = new VLLink;
        }
        vl_link->preLink = NULL;
        vl_link->nextLink = NULL;
        vl_link->link = NULL;

        VLLink* vl_link2 = NULL;
        while (vl_link2 == NULL)
        {
            vl_link2 = new VLLink;
        }
        vl_link2->preLink = NULL;
        vl_link2->nextLink = NULL;
        vl_link2->link = NULL;

        VL_list2[i] = vl_link;
        temp_VL_list2[i] = vl_link2;

    }
```

It will be ok!?

Comment: The memory for the arrays should certainly be available in the constructor, and I can't see anything wrong with the posted code apart from its ludicrous verbosity. Unless you're being paid per line of code, the entire body of the loop could be reduced to `VL_list2[i] = new VLLink(); temp_VL_list2[i] = new VLLink();`

Comment: Also: what in the world is "while (vl_link == NULL)" trying to accomplish?  What's VL_list2 and temp_VL_list2?

Comment: Nothing immediately leaps out to me (other than using a constructor like @MikeSeymour suggests and perhaps removing this linked list implementation entirely for std::list).  If changing it to two locals "fixes" the issue, then that suggests the this pointer is not pointing where it should.  How was this CNetworkEditor constructed?

Comment: The cause of the problem may well be outside the code you posted. What happens in the constructor before you enter the loop? What happens before you enter the constructor itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from @PeterHuene's suggestion to replace `VL_list` and `temp_VL_list` with something like `std::list<CPhysicalLink>` or similar, you should move the initialization of `VLLink` into the constructor, avoiding the code duplication in your loop

```
struct VLLink {
    VLLink() : link(NULL), prelink(NULL), nextlink(NULL) {}
    ...
};`
```

then you can reduce your loop as @MikeSeymour said

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_VL_NUM; i++) {
    VL_list[i] = new VLLink();
    temp_VL_list[i] = new VLLink();
}
```

A reason for your memory problem might be, that `MAX_VL_NUM` is larger than 10. So, you should either use `MAX_VL_NUM` everywhere or use 10 everywhere.

And now to your question ;-)

> If I change it to ... It will be ok!?

Nobody can answer this, because nobody knows what you want to achieve. My first reaction would be definitely *No!*, because moving variables around "just because" is almost always a bad idea. It's better to analyze the problem and fix the cause than to cure some random symptoms.

Your change would also modify the meaning from *member of a class* to *automatic variable* on the stack.

Comment: I want to know whether system allocates memory of size of 10*sizeof(VLLink*) or just a pointer for "VLLink* VL_list[10]"?

Comment: When the `CNetworkEditor` object is created, there's also space for 10 `VLLink*` for `VL_list` and another 10 `VLLink*` for `temp_VL_list`.